# I would like to identify these capacitor markings

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image]

So I can see it’s manufactured by wima, is 2000v dc and 700v ac rated, I’m unsure on what the 1000 is though, is it 1000uf or 1uf or something else ?.

Also what does the FKP1 and f5 relate to?.

Answer (score 2):

FKP1 indicates the "family" (a group of capacitors with similar characteristics) the capacitor belongs to.

The value is 1000 pF

F5 may be a date code - the data sheet doesn't indicate anything about the actual lable format.

You can go to https://wwww.wima.de and search for FKP1 to find the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, how do you know that it refers to PF ?, are they always quoted in PF or is this detailed on the datasheet ?

Comment: The datasheet tells all.  For a film capacitor such as that, 1000 uF is an impossible value, and I think 1000 nF is unlikely.